# How to remove inherited functions in sh (posix)

Tags: shell, sh

How do I ensure that there are no unexpected functions inherited from the parent when my script is run?  If using bash,

```
#!/bin/bash -p
```

will do the trick, as will invoking the script through env -i.  But I cannot rely on the user to invoke env, I don't want to rely on bash, I don't want to do an exec-hack and re-exec the script, and

```
#!/usr/bin/env -i sh
```

does not work.

So I'm looking for a portable way (portable == posix) to ensure that the user hasn't defined functions that will unexpectedly modify the behavior of the script.  My current solution is:

```
eval $( env | sed -n '/\([^=]*\)=(.*/s//\1/p' |
    while read -r name; do echo unset -f $name\;; done )
```

but that's pretty ugly and of dubious robustness.  Is there a good way to get the functionality that 'unset -f -a' should provide?

**edit**

Slightly less ugly, but no better (I don't like parsing the output of env):

```
unset -f $( env | sed -n '/\([^=]*\)=(.*/s//\1/p' | tr \\012 \  )
```

Comment: GNU Bash 5.0 does not have option `-p` according to its manual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash --posix
```

results in:

```
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
```

same as:

```
#!/bin/sh

SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
```

and "sh" is posix...

EDIT:

tested a few functions - unset was not required in my case...

EDIT2:

compare output of "set", not just "env"

EDIT3:

the following example - output of both "set|wc" also gives same results:

```
#!/bin/sh

set
set|wc

unset -f $( env | sed -n '/\([^=]*\)=(.*/s//\1/p' | tr \\012 \  )

set
set|wc
```

Comment: Parsing set is a good idea.  Setting SHELLOPTS won't work, since it is read only in bash.  unset is only required if the caller has exported the function.  (eg: $ ls() { echo foo; }; export -f ls; sh -c 'ls'; )

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following `env` shebang line that sets a reasonable `PATH` variable to invoke the `sh`  interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/xpg4/bin sh
```

Comment: That is an interesting thought.  I had forgotten about this question, and annoyed at myself for the lack of explanation; on the box I'm on today, #!/usr/bin/env -i sh does work!

Comment: @WilliamPursell passing more than one argument in a shebang line is not portable. it works on some systems, but not all.